# Advice on a certain regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am working on extracting links from an emails content and therefore using `Regex` and `String.Split` to extract the important information out of the already parsed `Content-type: text/html`.
Since I never got in touch with Regular Expressions until now I was using an Online Editor which I provided a part of my email and build my `Regex pattern` around it. Right now it seems to work perfectly fine but my code is a mess caused by me not fully understanding what I wrote.

The way I currently handle the links' extraction is by removing certain parts of the email (which are HTML-tags) and then splitting the obtained string twice.

This is the example I tested my `Regex` on (this is exactly what the Content looks like when I extract it as a string, I just replaced the used links with similar examples):

```
<div dir="ltr">

<div>Link text == link (link text would be changed to "Protected link"): 
    <a href="http://www.google.de" 
        target=5Fblank">
            Protected link
    </a>
</div>

<div>Link text != link (link text and link would be rewritten and not equal): 
    <a href="http://www.google.de">
        http://www.google.com
    </a>
</div>

<div>Link text != link (link would be rewritten but not link text):
    <a href="http://www.google.de">
        Click!
    </a>
</div>

<div>Link text != link (link would be not rewritten, in whitelist): 
    <a href="http://www.google.de">
        Click!
    </a>
</div>

<div>Link is not rewritten: 
    <a href="http://www.google.de">
        http://www.google.de
    </a>
</div>

<div>Link text != link (no protocol in link text and would be not rewritten): 
    <a href="http://www.google.de">
        www.google.de
    </a>
</div>
```

And the `Regular Expression` I used looks like this:

```
"(href=\"[a-zA-Z0-9-:/.=?]*\"*[a-zA-Z0-9=\" ]*)([>a-zA-Z0-9-:/.,;\"=!? \t\n]*)"
```

---

After writing the extracted links and link texts to an array I split those twice.
 Firstly at this `>` character and after that if the extracted string starts with `href="` and split at `"` characters.

```
var linkParser = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] links = new string[linkParser.Matches(text).Count];

int t = 0;
foreach (Match ma in linkParser.Matches(text))
{
    links[t] = ma.Value;
    t++;
}

var list = new List<String[]>();
string[] temp;

for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
{
    temp = links[i].Split('>');
    list.Add(temp);
}

var pairs = new List<String[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    string[] tmp = list[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Length; j++)
    {
        if (tmp[j].StartsWith("href=\""))
        {
            pairs.Add(new String[]
            {
                tmp[j].Split(new string[]
                {
                    "href=\""
                }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('"')[0], tmp[j + 1]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find it much easier to solve this problem using an HTML DOM parser such as HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: When i tried to open up their website yesterday it didn't load (I guess maintenance) so I tried to solve the problem by using regex. I'll look into it later on and see if it helps me out. My method works for me right now so i can use it to get the links' response code but I see my pattern struggling at some point in the future

Comment: You can (and probably should) install HTML Agility Pack through NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Comment: I am always installing packs through NuGet but I need the documentation to make a good use of it

Comment: The site is up now, at least for me. If it's down you can still probably find good examples similar to your own needs here on stack overflow, or find an "intro to" blog post somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Since links are enclosed in quotes ", you can simplify your regex to this (href="[^"]+"). To clarify it, it matches href=", then matches any number (more than one) of any character except for the quote ", then the quote " character.

You can also use groups to get the link directly instead of splitting/replacing the string</s>
Since you need both the link and its text, try this:
**Edited:**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "<a href=\"(?<link>[^ \"]+)\"[^>]*>(?<text>(.|\n)*?)(?=(<\\/a>))<\\/a>");
for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{matches[i].Groups["link"].Value} {matches[i].Groups["text"].Value}");
}
```

The output for this is:

```
http://www.google.de             Protected link    
http://www.google.de         http://www.google.com    
http://www.google.de         Click!    
http://www.google.de         Click!    
http://www.google.de         http://www.google.de    
http://www.google.de         www.google.de
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: This allows me to get the link but not the link text which is required for security checks

Comment: what do you mean by "link but not the link text"?

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.de">Click!</a> href is the link and "Click!" the link text

Comment: it seems to work in some certain cases. I will link you a pastebin link to the output which i get from my example i tested it on: https://pastebin.com/pKECZbTu